# Illuminator badge, too hard to get?

Tags: discussion, badges

Looking through the [badges page](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges) today, I noticed there is only a single badge that no one has ever earned here, the Illuminator badge.

**description**

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer
>   score > 0)

Is this badge too hard to get? The requirements are very high, if a user like [oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) with more rep than most of us put together (162,760 and counting) can't earn this badge, perhaps the requirements need to be lower?

As I said before it is the only badge no one has ever earned on Ask Ubuntu.

Are any of the 20k+ users even close to this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the description. You have to edit and answer 500 questions in 12 hours? o.O Or it counts every time you edit and answer a question in less than 12 hours between the two events?

Comment: You have to edit the question and then answer it, with at least one vote on your answer, within 12 hours of when you made the edit and do it 500 times (not in one day, that would be crazy). @AndreaLazzarotto

Comment: First task: answer 500 proper questions that aren't duplicates or downright lazy. Make sure they have a good title, tags and are reasonably scoped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's brand new.  Some people had the previous "almost unattainable badge" reversal.

So, no.  Not too hard.

Comment: Oh, that would explain it, I did not know it was new, I thought it had just been sat there for years, thanks.

Comment: @MarkKirby a year, I think. Sometime last year. I'm at 290+/500.

Comment: @muru A year is not so long and you seem well on your way to getting one, I only have 14/500 long way to go :)